# Why can't I get sudo to ask for password?

Tags: amazon-ec2, passwords, sudo

This is my sudoers file on a new ubuntu ec2 box. Why doesn't `sudo su` still require a password?

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) PASSWD:ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) PASSWD:ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) PASSWD:ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Is there some sort of delay? Are you suppose to "source" it or something similar like you would do with a bashrc file? Why is it so difficult to make `sudo su` ask for a password?

EDIT:
Per [this](https://alestic.com/2009/04/ubuntu-ec2-sudo-ssh-rsync/) link, running:

```
sudo passwd ubuntu
sudo perl -pi -e 's/^(ubuntu.*)NOPASSWD:(.*)/$1$2/' /etc/sudoers
```

Doesn't work, nor does it even change the sudoers file.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `PASSWD:ALL` on following three locations

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) 

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) 

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL)
```